# Why am I wrong in calculating this limit?

Tags: limits

I want to calculate the limit of the following expression when $\omega \rightarrow\infty$
$$
\exp \left(r^2 \left(-\left| \frac{\mu  \omega }{2}-0.1 \exp (0.5 \log [\omega ]) \mu \right| \right)-\mu  r \left(1-0.1 \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{0.1 \mu } \log [\omega ]\right)\right)\right) \tag{1}
$$
where $\mu>0$, so I write
$$
\log[\infty]=\infty\Rightarrow \text{erf}[\infty]=1\Rightarrow\text{second term becomes: }-0.9 \mu r
$$
also
$$
\log[\infty]=\infty\Rightarrow \text{exp}[\infty]=\infty \text{ and }\frac{\mu\infty}{2}=\infty\Rightarrow\text{first term becomes: }\infty-\infty=0
$$
but when I evaluate $1$ in Mathematica, it yields $\infty$. Why?

Comment: "*first term becomes $\infty-\infty=0$*"  To be clear, $\infty-\infty$ is undefined and needs closer inspection.  It could have been anything.

Comment: $\infty - \infty$ is far from being $0$. In fact it's far from being anything. It's just undefined. Hint: $\exp(\frac{1}{2}\ln(w)) = \sqrt{w}$ so you can write first exponent as $\exp\big( r^2( -w| \frac{\mu}{2} - \frac{\mu}{10}\frac{1}{\sqrt{w}}|)\big)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek I didn't your mean, How can I deal with this limit?